# how to use if condition inside $(document).ready(function() in cshtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

trying to disable two html.Textboxfor field on condition.Not working .Looks like syntax issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        if (Model.Key == Guid.Empty) {
            $("#@idPasswordTextBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#@idConfirmPasswordTextBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

});
```

Is that a way to use `if` condition inside `$(document).ready(function() {}`?

Comment: your IDs start with an `@` symbol?

Comment: Try removing the `@` symbols from your selectors. In effect, `#idPasswordTextBox` instead of `#@idPasswordTextBox`.

Comment: those are local variables defined as:   string idPasswordTextBox = "_Password_" + @Model.Key.ToString();
 string idConfirmPasswordTextBox = "_ConfirmPassword_" + @Model.Key.ToString();  and ids are assigned as:  @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { id = @idPasswordTextBox })

Comment: It was working fine until I added that if condition.

Comment: It worked finally with the following code: @if (Model.Key != Guid.Empty) {
    <text>
   $("#@idPasswordTextBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $("#@idConfirmPasswordTextBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    </text>
  }

Comment: Ids were defined as: string idPasswordTextBox = "_Password_" + @Model.Key.ToString();
 string idConfirmPasswordTextBox = "_ConfirmPassword_" + @Model.Key.ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your razor code in ( )

```
if (Model.Key == Guid.Empty) {
        $("#@(idPasswordTextBox)").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#@(idConfirmPasswordTextBox)").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
```

should escape the javascript string

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(Model.Key == Guid.Empty) {
    <text>$("#idPasswordTextBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');</text>
}
```

remove `@` from your selector, or use double `@@`

```
@if(Model.Key == Guid.Empty) {
    <text>$("#@@idPasswordTextBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');</text>
}
```

Comment: don't understand you.. so you need to Razor if or you need to invoke the click handler of checkbox only if `if` condition is valid?

Comment: I am sorry, It worked ,though it was showing syntax error. Not sure what happened .But thanks a lot. I needed to Razor if.